# Lost Connection to Host Aptana

Tags: aptana, host

I'm using Aptana 3 to build a website in a group project. Last night I finished my assignment of creating a functional log in page, checked it several times to make sure it was working correctly, saved my work, closed Aptana down. 
This morning when I woke up I went to check my log in page again and there was nothing there. Just a blank white screen. In Aptana under the folder Advanced Web Applications, where the entire website is contained, there is a small red "X" on the folder icon. 
When I open the folder and check all the other folders and files there  are no errors. 
Does anyone know how to fix this? Or what the issue might be?
Thanks in advance.